# versioning settings

Tags: 2007

There are two types of versioning settings available in sharepoint library. Major and minor versions.
But minor versions will show the versions as 1.1,1.2 ,1.3 ........to 1.9 .then it will move to 2.0
Is it possible to make the version in a pattern of  1.01,1.02,1.03.....1.99 ?

Answer (score 2):

What you are suggesting isnt possible in SharePoint, and probably hard to implement too.
In SharePoint 2010 you can create custom document id's where you can control prefixes
http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/04/13/sp-2010-sharepoint-server-2010-creating-your-custom-document-id-provider.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is correct. I think that after 1.9 you'll get 1.10, 1.11, 1.12, etc..

You should only get 2.0 after publishing a second major version.

If I remember correctly, you can 512 minor versions, and 512 major versions (therefore, 512x512 versions in total)